# release apk installs but crashes when launched. The app runs perfectly on debug mode. I looked up on the Android Studio and this is my adb logcat.

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apk, release

The release apk works perfectly without any errors. But when i can generate release apk, it installs on my android device but it crashes as soon as it launches.

you can find my code [here](https://github.com/AnitaLama/AnitaLama.github.io/tree/master/wine)

[this is the logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZuA7.png)

please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

that right, this issue is occur on android 6.
This problem relative to permission on android 6. Please update your CLI to latest version.
Run

```
"npm install titanium -g"
"npm install appcelerator -g"
"appc setup"
```

Regards

Comment: can you please tell where and how am i supposed to do these?
I am new to react native.

Comment: I'm using IDE Android Studio for build file apk release.

Comment: You can refer guideline: https://www.decoide.org/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: i followed the same guideline. But i cant seem to run the release apk at all.
logcat says the error is "unable to get realpath for the library "/ ../.. /.../libreactnativejni.so". Will use given name

Comment: are you build app on device android 6.0?

Comment: Yes I am using android 6.0

Comment: Thank you so much.
You saved my life.